# error: overloaded function with no contextual type information usinf LEMON-graph-library

Tags: c++, debugging, callback, gurobi, lemon-graph-library

So I am implementing a Benders procedure using lazy constraints from GUROBI. As part of the subproblem procedure I need to process a graph using Breadth First Search, for which I am using LEMON. I am trying to implement use a visitor for the BFS search. However when I try to access the map of reached nodes using bfs.reached() I get a compiler (I suppose) error.

Here is the callback class implementation so far:

```
typedef   ListDigraph::Node                          Node;
typedef   ListDigraph::Arc                           Arc;
typedef   ListDigraph::ArcMap<double>                ArcDou;
typedef   ListDigraph::NodeMap<double>               NodeDou;
typedef   ListDigraph::ArcMap<int>                   ArcInt;
typedef   ListDigraph::ArcMap<bool>                  ArcBool;
typedef   ListDigraph::NodeMap<int>                  NodeInt;
typedef   ListDigraph::NodeIt                        NodeIt;
typedef   ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph>::NodeIt        NodeIt_rev;
typedef   ListDigraph::ArcIt                         ArcIt;
class BendersSub: public GRBCallback
{
  public:
   
    const Instance_data &ins;
    const vec4GRBVar    &X;
    const vec1GRBvar    &u;
    vec2GRBVar    &p;
    GRBModel &modelSubD;
    BendersSub(const Instance_data &ins,  const vec4GRBVar &X, const vec1GRBvar &u, vec2GRBVar &p,  GRBModel &modelSubD)
    :ins(ins), X(X), u(u), p(p),modelSubD(modelSubD){
          //cout << "\n\tI:" << ins.I << " J:" << ins.J << " T:" << ins.T << " V:" << ins.V << flush;
    }
  protected:
    void callback() {
      try {
          
           if (where == GRB_CB_MIPSOL) {
              cout << "\n -- Entering Callback -- " << flush;
              
              string var_name;  
              int I = ins.I , J = ins.I , T = ins.T , V = ins.V,i,j,k,t,v;
              
              
                          ListDigraph grafo;
                          Node x;
                  
                          for( int t(0); t < ins.T+1; t++)
                            for ( int i(0); i < ins.I; i++)
                              x = grafo.addNode();
                    
                          
                          Arc arco;
                          int count( 0 );
                          for(t = 0; t < ins.T; ++t){
                             for(i = 0; i < ins.I; ++i){
                                for(j = 0; j < ins.J; ++j){
                                    if ( i == j ){
                                        arco = grafo.addArc(grafo.nodeFromId(i + ins.I * t),grafo.nodeFromId(j + (ins.I * (t+1))));
                                    }else if ( (t + ins.tau.at(i).at(j)) <= ins.T-1 ){  
                                        arco = grafo.addArc(grafo.nodeFromId(i + ins.I * t),grafo.nodeFromId(j + ins.I * (t + ins.tau.at(i).at(j))));
                                    }
                                    else if ( (t + ins.tau.at(i).at(j)) > ins.T-1 ){
                                        arco = grafo.addArc(grafo.nodeFromId(i + ins.I * t),grafo.nodeFromId(((ins.I*(ins.T+1)+1))-1-(ins.I)+j)) ;
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                          }
                            
                          
                          NodeDou divergence (grafo);
                          ArcDou  costo      (grafo);
                          ArcBool filter     (grafo, true);
                          NodeDou potential         (grafo);
                          
                          ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph> grafo_r(grafo);
                          using Visitor = Visitor_AcSup<NodeDou>;
              
              
              for ( int v(0); v < V; v++){
                   
                
                        double sum_sup(0.0);
                        Visitor visitor(grafo_r, divergence, sum_sup);
                        cout << "\nsum_sup: " << sum_sup << flush;
                        for (t = 0; t < T; t++){
                            for(i = 0; i < I ; i++){
                                if(divergence[grafo.nodeFromId(flat_ixt(ins,t,i))] < -EPS3){
                                    BfsVisit<ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph>, Visitor> bfs(grafo_r,visitor);
                                    bfs.run(grafo.nodeFromId(flat_ixt(ins,t,i)));
                                    if( (sum_sup-fabs(divergence[grafo.nodeFromId(flat_ixt(ins,t,i))]))  < -EPS4 ){
                                        cout << "\nBuild Ray" << flush;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        for (NodeIt_rev  u(grafo_r); u != INVALID; ++u){
                            /*The error does not show when I comment this line.*/
                            cout << "\nId: " << grafo.id(u) << setw(10) << bfs.reached(u) << flush;
                        }
                        cout << "\nsum_sup: " << sum_sup << flush;
                        .
                        /* Remaining code */
                        .
                        .
               }/*end_if v*/

              
               
               //cout << "\n -- Exiting Callback -- " << flush;
         }
         
        
      }catch (GRBException e) {
        cout << "Error number: " << e.getErrorCode() << endl;
        cout << e.getMessage() << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }catch (const exception &exc){
        cerr << "\nCallback - " << exc.what() << flush;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }catch (...) {
        cout << "Error during callback" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
};
```

Here is the (incomplete visitor) implementation.

```
template <typename DivMap >
class Visitor_AcSup : public BfsVisitor< const ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph> > {
public:
    Visitor_AcSup(const ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph>& _graph, DivMap& _dirMap, double& _sum_sup)
    : graph(_graph), dirMap(_dirMap), sum_sup(_sum_sup){
        cout << "\n --Calling constructor of Visitor_AcSup -- " << endl;
        sum_sup = 0.0;
    }
    
    void start (const Node &node){
        //cout << "\nstart Node: " << graph.id(node) << flush;
        sum_sup -= dirMap[node];
    }
    void reach (const Node &node){
        //cout << "\nReach Node: " << graph.id(node) << flush;
    }
    void process (const Node &node){
        //cout << "\nProcess Node: " << graph.id(node) << setw(5) << dirMap[node] << flush;
        sum_sup += dirMap[node];
    }
    void discover(const Arc& arc) {
        //cout << "\tDiscover Arc: " << graph.id(arc) << flush;
    }
    void examine(const Arc& arc) {
        //cout << "\tExamine Arc: " << graph.id(arc) << flush;
    }  
    
private:
  const ReverseDigraph<ListDigraph>& graph;  
  DivMap& dirMap;
  double& sum_sup;
```

The error looks like this

```
functions.cpp:1845:59: error: overloaded function with no contextual type information
        cout << "\nId: " << grafo.id(u) << setw(10) << bfs.reached(u) << flush;
                                                           ^~~~~~~
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'VAP' failed
```

I am clueless about what is happening as the only error that comes up to my mind is conflict of keywords between namespaces

```
using namespace lemon;
using namespace lemon::concepts;
using namespace std;
```

but have found no resolution to this. I am a newbie in C++, so that I am asking you guys where this could possibly come from.

Comment: I recommend using the Python API of Gurobi and networkx to do the graph computations. Then, if your prototype is working fine and you require the extra performance you can still re-implement the code in C++.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I will think about it because this is just a snippet of the whole code and to tell you the truth it would be rewriting lots of code and i don't know if I have the time. Also, the results from this work are to be compared with results from other method implemented by me in C/C++, then it seems unfair to do that. I am still going to take a look at the tools you pointed out, ponder how long it would take and decide. I appreciate your responder sir.